# Accepting an array as a read-only parameter without making a copy

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way in Visual Basic .NET to write a function that accepts an array parameter in a read-only way? That is, the function should be able to use the data in the array, but not be able to modify the elements (i.e. an attempt to modify should result in a compilation error). I am seeking a way that would not require making a copy of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure...use [IEnumerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Collections.IEnumerator.aspx):

> Enumerators can be used to read the data in the collection, but they
>   cannot be used to modify the underlying collection.

Example:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim values() As Integer = {2, 4, 6, 3, 7, 1}
    Foo(values.GetEnumerator)
End Sub

Private Sub Foo(ByVal iter As IEnumerator)
    Dim x As Integer
    While iter.MoveNext
        ' ... do something with "iter.Current" ...
        x = iter.Current
        Debug.Print(x)
    End While
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the [ReadOnlyCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx) to do this

```
Dim values() As Int32= {2, 4, 6, 3, 7, 1}
Dim readOnlyValues As New ReadOnlyCollection(Of Int32)(values)
```

This has the advantage of using it like you are used to with INDEX or FOR EACH methods.